# Table from Microsoft access to html

Tags: css, html, ms-access

I have this [table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmNiJ.jpg) and i want add that (the one inside the black squear) to the future web, but i only manage do a table, this is the entire code

```
<!DOCUMENTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Asuntos Pendientes</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main-body">
  <div class="body-data">
    <div class="tabla">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Fecha</th>
                <th>Servicio</th>
                <th>Asunto</th>
                <th>Fecha a Controlar</th>
                <th>Fecha de Resolucion</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="input-data">
        <label>ID</label><input id="ID" type="text"><br>
        <label>Fecha</label><input id="fecha" type="date"><br>
        <label>Servicio</label><input id="servicio" type="text"><br>
        <label>Fecha a Controlar</label><input id="fechaControlar" type="date"><br>
        <label>Fecha de Resolucion</label><input id="fechaResolucion" type="date"><br>
        <label>Asunto</label><textarea id="asunto" placeholder="Asunto"></textarea><br>
        <label>Detalle</label><textarea id="detalle" placeholder="Detalle"></textarea><br>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-botones">
    <a href="index.html" id="botonCerrar">Cerrar Formulario</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

can be done in other way? because i need a table who expands when i insert or delete data.

Comment: Where is your code? And what *other way*?